# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDDL_DEVOBJ_SYS_ALL_ADM_RWX_WORLD_RW_RES_R

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wdk, kmdf

I was searching for the above link error on Visual Studio 2013 KMDF driver project.

Since Linker errors are associated with libraries, i do not have a sample code. But let me share my solution for future developers who come across this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the above error when I was building a code that I had got from a different driver developer.

Reason for error:
Linker's additional dependencies were not properly setup for all Configuration settings on Visual Studio (2013)

To solve this error add the following in additional libraries path:

Right click on the project > Properties > Linker > All Options > Additional Dependencies

modify the default dependency:

> > %(AdditionalDependencies);

to

> > %(AdditionalDependencies);$(DDK_LIB_PATH)\wdmsec.lib